# Windows "llvm bison" equivalent not cygwin?

Tags: c, cygwin, llvm

What is windows equivalent for "llvm and bison or yacc " Linux on windows not using cygwin or mingw?

Isn't there another parser and AST generator for Windows?

Comment: The equivalents are `llvm`, `bison`/`yacc`, etc. Last time I checked them they also run under Windows. What is your **actual** problem? And "Linux on **W**indows" does not make much sense. Unless you mean "smart" **w**indows which include some embedded Linux board to open/close the window automatically or by WLAN.

Comment: But I should use Clang to compile them on windows or use cygwin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiling with Clang isn't a problem. You can visit [this page](http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStartedVS.html) which is a guide using llvm with Visual Studio.